# Multipart file upload in singlerequest in phonegap android

Tags: android, file-upload, cordova, multipart

I have a three audio files stored into array. I want to upload the files into server into a single request with filekey values 'utterence1','utterence2','utterence3' but in a phone gap [FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) method  in single request only upload one file with key value 'utterence1'. But I need to upload three files in to single request.How can i do this?

Comment: Not currently supported. so I think files one at a time in a loop seems like reasonable option.